# How to fix this Number System Converter error?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

[Error NSC Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iJb4.png)

[Error NSC 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KzFT.png)

[Error NSC 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vr3N.png)

[Error NSC 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95uQV.png)

[Debug Error NSC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2O4o.png)

[Debug Error NSC 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAIuF.png)

I want to run this Number System Converter program that using kivy also kivy framework, but somehow the screen won't show up. I already installed all requirements tools in order to run it. But still couldn't run smoothly.

https://github.com/Miriskrit/NumberSystemConverter-python
This is the source app I got.

This is the error I got:

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 700, in _apply_rule
     setattr(widget_set, key, value)
   File "kivy\weakproxy.pyx", line 35, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__setattr__
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 520, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 549, in kivy.properties.Property.set
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 748, in kivy.properties.NumericProperty.convert
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 769, in kivy.properties.NumericProperty.parse_list
 TypeError: Expected unicode, got float

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\Users\HP\Downloads\Compressed\NumberSystemConverter-python-master\main.py", line 315, in <module>
     MyApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 954, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 924, in _run_prepare
     root = self.build()
   File "c:\Users\HP\Downloads\Compressed\NumberSystemConverter-python-master\main.py", line 311, in build
     return Container()
   File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\kivy\uix\boxlayout.py", line 145, in __init__
     super(BoxLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\kivy\uix\layout.py", line 76, in __init__
     super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 366, in __init__
     self.apply_class_lang_rules(
   File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 470, in apply_class_lang_rules
     Builder.apply(
   File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 540, in apply
     self._apply_rule(
   File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 709, in _apply_rule
     raise BuilderException(rule.ctx, rule.line,
 kivy.lang.builder.BuilderException: Parser: File "c:\Users\HP\Downloads\Compressed\NumberSystemConverter-python-master\my.kv", line 255:
 ...
     253:                MDIconButton:
     254:                    user_font_size: "32sp"
 >>  255:                    user_font_size:(dp(48), dp (48))
     256:                    icon: "delete-circle-outline"
     257:                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .9, "center_y": .24}
 ...
 TypeError: Expected unicode, got float
   File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 700, in _apply_rule
     setattr(widget_set, key, value)
   File "kivy\weakproxy.pyx", line 35, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__setattr__
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 520, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 549, in kivy.properties.Property.set
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 748, in kivy.properties.NumericProperty.convert
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 769, in kivy.properties.NumericProperty.parse_list
```

Answer (score 0):

The `user_font_size` property is a `NumericProperty`, so you should assign a single number to it, not a tuple. Try changing:

```
user_font_size:(dp(48), dp (48))
```

to:

```
user_font_size: dp(48)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, sir. Its working! I just did what you told. I change `user_font_size:(dp(48), dp (48))` to `user_font_size: dp(48)` exactly in my.kv line 255, line 143, and line 136. Works like a charm, bless you sir.